# How do I share views on multisite in drupal 8

Tags: views, 8

Is it possible to have a multisite set up in drupal 8 and create view on Site A and have that appear on Site B?  I cant find anything in drupal documentation for sharing views.  I can share users, content, and taxonomy, but nothing else.

Comment: Probably not since views are config entities and not content entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multisite sharing works by using the same prefix for certain tables. It's dark magic, especially in 8.x, with the automatically created entity and field tables.

Since all config is stored in the same table, that's not possible.

You *could* write a custom config storage controller that stores certain config in a shared table, but that seems like a very crazy idea to me.

Configuration can be exported/imported and probably doesn't change that often. There will also be modules like features and others that will make re-using configuration easier.

I would also strongly recommend to consider other options to share your content. I can't imagine that this works reliably in 8.x.

Comment: Thanks.  I am just exploring all options.  I know table prefixing is the quick and dirty way to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach. With CMI, you could export your view (when it has changed) on site A and import it on site B (using [drush config-merge](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/docs/cm.md) or rsync). I did this already with D8 testing sites and it worked nicely IIRC. Sure it's less flexible and granular than really sharing a 'live' view between 2 sites but chances that you want to update your view frequently are equally low, aren't they?